# iOS and Mac "transform rotate" not working

Tags: ios, css

I have a problem with iOS + Mac. I need to flip card with "transform rotate" but It's not working. Can you please give me some advice how to solve this issue and fix it? 
Windows browsers + Android is working just fine.
Code:

```
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
```

Link to full code: 
https://codepen.io/Sublit/pen/ajvdya

Answer (score 0):

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.75, curve: .easeIn)
animator.addAnimations {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(180).degreeToRadians)
            }
animator.startAnimation()
```

You can find `degreeToRadians` here :

```
import UIKit

extension CGFloat {
    var degreeToRadians: CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180
    }

    var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat {
        return self * 180 / .pi
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with iOS, it seams like having transform value multiplied by 90 not working, once is rotated it will disappear. simplest solution, if it feet your needs, is to rotate only 179 deg, this way will stay visible